# Array out of bound exception in calling method, How to return whole array from a method

Tags: java, insertion-sort

This program is basic insertion sort. I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at line numbers 22 and 44. Help me in solving this issue.How to return sorted whole array from insertion method. 
return a[] is not working..............................................

```
package analysis;

import java.util.*;

class Sort
{
    int i,j,n,temp;
    int a[] = new int[n];

    int insertion(int a[],int n)
    {
        for (i=1;i<n;i++) {
            j=i-1;
            while (i>0 && a[j]>a[i]) {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;
                i--;
                j--;
            }
        }
        return a[n];
    }
}

class Recurse
{
    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("enter array size");
        int l,s;
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        s = sc.nextInt();
        int b[] = new int[s];
        int c[] = new int[s];
        for (l=0;l<s;l++) {
            b[l] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        Sort so = new Sort();
        c[s] = so.insertion(b,s);
        System.out.println("Sorted array is ");
        for (l=0;l<s;l++) {
            System.out.println(c[l]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and safer to just use `Arrays.sort` ?

Answer (score 1):

Those two lines of your code causes the problem:

```
int a[] = new int[n];
return a[n];
```

Returning the element at `n` index is impossible because indexing include numbers from `0` to `n-1`.

Comment: How to return the whole sorted array, from insertion method given above.Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: If you want to return the array in a function it should look like: int[] function() { int[] array = new int[10]; return array; } Please accept my answer as the correct one if it helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

At line 44 you try to access `c[l]` from `0` to `s` but you only declared `c[s]`